# Disqus not showing on panel page only (panel set as homepage)

Tags: 7, panels, comments

Version Disqus `7.x-1.12`
Drupal `7.38`
Disqus is only not showing on my panel page. On all the other pages, Disqus is shown. It has shown before on the same panel. I wish I knew all the things I did between the last time it appeared and when I noticed, but I don't.

## Things I tried to no avail:

in the configuration settings (`admin/config/services/disqus`)

I tried adding the block into a region
* **Visiblity-**    All node types selected; *Location:* Block
* **Default options-** All node types selected
* **Behaviour-** *Localisation support:* unchecked; *Inherit User Credentials:* checked
* **Advanced-** *User Access Token:* correct value; *Public Key:* correct value: *Secret Key:* correct value;
**Visibility** also set it to *content area* and weight tried 0, 50, 100, -100

#### Drupal Issue [1159690](https://www.drupal.org/node/1159690):

Doesn't correlate entirely to my issue because the HTML seems to be there (and not with me), but I suppose it was worth trying some ideas still.

[Comment #9](https://www.drupal.org/node/1159690#comment-4685998) insert `<?php
print render($content['disqus']);
?>` into template

[Comment #60](https://www.drupal.org/node/1159690#comment-10421093) suggest to simply hit save again on said configuration page and somehow that would be all it took.

#### Drupal issue [928354](https://www.drupal.org/node/928354)

About panels integration. Patch at [comment #17](https://www.drupal.org/node/928354#comment-9938245) no worky.

#### panel config:

Tried inserting the disQus block in every possible region of my Panel to no avail.

I also tried this (as mentioned in above [issue](https://www.drupal.org/node/928354)  )

> #
>   in /admin/settings/disqus underneath the Visibility section, choose the Block option in the Location dropdown menu.
>
> Then you just select the "Disqus Comments" block from within the panels interface under the Miscellaneous tab.

On my panel page, when I do a `dpm()` of `$node` inside of the `node.tpl.php` file, there are 2 node objects in my *Krumo*. In each object there actually is an array for Diqus. This makes sense, because it is Disqus applied to the nodes *inside* of the panel. These comments don't show either though, but I don't want them to of course. I want 1 Disqus applied to my panel obviously instead.

#### Blocks configuration

I put the Disqus comments block in different regions of my theme, still same problem: showing up in other regions

Tried activating a different theme, same problem: Disqus shows on every page except the panel.

Updated the module to `7.x-1.12+5-dev`, flushed cashes. Nothing changed.

Comment: How many nodes are in your panel?

Comment: @oksana Inside this panel there are those 2 nodes. In fact, there are 2 views in this panel, each outputting just 1 node. I.o.w., nodes inside of views inside of a panel.

Comment: Disqus is looking for context variables in panels. When you place disqus comment block in a panel that overrides node template,  it finds node ID from url (node/%node) and uses that to render comments. When you create a custom panel page that contains two nodes as views - disqus block can't locate node ids to use for comment rendering.

Comment: Try inserting your nodes as existing node, not views, and see if disqus works.

Comment: I made a panel where inserted existing nodes straight away like you asked and just to see what happens then, but still no Disqus below it. I noticed you talked about when I want to place a Disqus block inside a panel. For the record, I did more things that just try to put a block inside the panel. (explained in my question) and frankly I don't care what exactly makes disqus show up below my panel, just as long as it does. Also, it is actually important that the panel has the views with one row; it has dropdowns as exposed filters and this functionality contains the actual value of the site

Comment: Also, if you look at my paragraph before **Blocks configuration** , I'm addressing that I realize that disqus as a block inside a panel is looking for the node ID's inside the panel, while what I want is Disqus below the panel and applied to the panel. In order to achieve the latter, I addressed that I tried applying the block OR region earlier in the question.

Comment: Overlooked the fact that Disqus doesn't have an ability to render multiple comment threads on one page out of the box(disqus QA [link](https://help.disqus.com/customer/portal/questions/6590005-is-there-a-way-to-post-two-disqus-comment-boxes-on-one-page-)). It's an old discussion but it still applies. Here's related info about optional implementations(fresh answers at the bottom) - [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4963505/several-disqus-threads-on-one-page). Those solutions do not apply to Drupal module. If you come up with a working implementation, please post an answer.

Comment: Please read my question and comments. What you mentioned doesn't apply to this particular issue. Again, I do not want comment boxes for each node inside my panel separately. I want just one comment box on the bottom of the page of which the URL is the one of the panel itself and therefore only applied to the entire panel. As I stated in the beginning of my question the comment box that I wanted was there and now something made it disappear. That is what I'm trying to figure out.

Answer (score 0):

A workaround I found in [this](https://www.drupal.org/node/1275844#comment-7357602) comment #5 out of the Disqus issuequeue adding disqus on the frontend.

```
    function HOOK_preprocess_page(&$vars) {
  if (module_exists('disqus')) {
    $identifier = $_GET['q'];
    if (strstr($identifier, 'path/to/add/comments/to')) {
      $domain = variable_get('disqus_domain', ''); // A.K.A. short name
      $url = url($_GET['q'], array('absolute' => true));
      $title = drupal_get_title();
      drupal_add_js(drupal_get_path('module', 'disqus') . '/disqus.js');
      drupal_add_js(array('disqus' => array('domain' => $domain, 'url' => $url, 'title' => $title, 'identifier' => $identifier)), 'setting'); // Add to the Drupal.settings for the script above to be able to pick it up.
      // Add the div to the page for the Disqus embed script to be able to drop in the comments code dynamically.
      $vars['page']['content']['system_main']['main']['#markup'] .= '<div id="disqus_thread"></div>';
    }
  }
}
```

Still curious about what it is in the backend that made the comment box disappear below the Panel though. I also disabled all the modules apart from the Disqus, panel en core, but still nothing.